# Extracting specific values from a object of type Reading(Reading is the object returned when loading a NEM13 file)

Tags: python

I would like to extract certain values from the output generated using the NEM Reader package in python, which loads a csv file and returns a NEMFile object. I thought of converting this object to a string and use regex to extract certain values but so far, it has been fruitless.

I would like some clarity as how to go about this. The code provided below is what I have achieved so far,

```
import re 
import os
import pandas as pd
from nemreader import read_nem_file

nem_file = read_nem_file("NEM13 file/AEMO556810778013NEM13.csv")


for nmi in nem_file.readings:
    for suffix in nem_file.readings[nmi]:
        for reading in nem_file.readings[nmi][suffix][-1:]:
            print(reading)
```

A sample output generated is the following:

Reading(t_start=datetime.datetime(2003, 10, 15, 10, 3, 33), t_end=datetime.datetime(2004, 1, 7, 10, 3, 33), read_value=418.0, uom='kWh', meter_serial_number='R4ZFLS6ZY1UV', quality_method='A', event_code='', event_desc='', read_start=55893.0, read_end=56311.0)

For example, if I would want to extract the 'meter_serial_number' from the following output, I was wondering how to achieve that.

Comment: `Reading` is not a standard python class. You will need to read the documentation from the library's authors or look at the source code to figure out how to use it.

Comment: As a guess, I would try `reading.meter_serial_number`. To understand this guess and be able to come up with it yourself, I suggest you learn about classes in Python.